# Uses of adverbial phrases

Tags: sentence-construction

> I have broken the rock with hammer at my home before.
>   I have broken the rock at my home with hammer before.

Explain which of the sentence is correct at the situation when use with hammer.

Comment: They are both correct, but need an article ("the hammer" or "a hammer") and some context to make any sense beyond that. In particular, "I've [done something] before" with no further clause is really only used in a specific kind of spoken phrase where you assert that you have the knowledge or experience to accomplish something.

Comment: If this is a lesson or exam question, can you tell us what the question asks you to do? If possible, can you add the entire question to _your_ question by using the **[edit]** link?

Answer (score -1):

*Hammer* needs an article: either definite (*the*) or indefinite (*a*).

The placement of *at my home* is important:

> I have broken the rock **at my home** with **a** hammer before.
>
> I have broken **a** rock with **a** hammer **at my home** before.

In the first sentence, you suggest that you've broken a certain rock (the one in your house) with a hammer before. In the second sentence, you suggest something totally different: that you've broken rocks with a hammer before, and those events took place at your house.

The use of certain articles is also important:

> I have broken **the** rock with **a** hammer at my home before.
>
> I have broken **a** rock with **a** hammer at my home before.
>
> I have broken **a** rock with **the** hammer at my home before.
>
> I have broken **the** rock with **the** hammer at my home before.

All the sentences have different meanings:

- The first sentence talks about a certain rock, and that you've broken this certain rock with a hammer before at your home.
- The second sentence, as previously stated, suggests that you've broken rocks with a hammer before, and it happened at your home each time.
- The third sentence talks about a certain hammer (the hammer at my home), and that you've used this certain hammer to break rocks before at your home.
- The fourth sentence can suggest two things:

  - you've broken a certain rock with a certain hammer; or
  - you've broken a special rock that has a design of a hammer on it.